Is there a centralized Fluent Bit agent monitoring tool?
We are using Fluent Bit in our environment to send OS-level logs to our SIEM. I'm looking for a way to centrally monitor the agents -- what hosts they're on, what version they're at, nothing fancy.
Is there a tool that can do this, or a way to configure Fluent Bit to do something like this for me?

As of now, there is no dedicated centralized Fluent Bit agent monitoring tool provided by the Fluent Bit project itself. One third party solution is to use Prometheus + Grafana.
